# Docker registry created not accessible inside cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress, docker-registry

I am using a EKS cluster over aws

I have create docker registry as a deployment and then created a svc and an ingress over it

In the ingress , I have placed tls secrets for the ingress Host

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.org/client-max-body-size: "0"
  creationTimestamp: "2021-06-18T05:10:02Z"
  generation: 1
  name: registry-ingress
  namespace: devops
  resourceVersion: "4126584"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/devops/ingresses/registry-ingress
  uid: d808177b-cb0b-4da2-82aa-5ab2f3c99109
spec:
  rules:
  - host: docker-registry.xxxx.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: docker-registry
          servicePort: 5000
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - docker-registry.xxxx.com
    secretName: tls-registry
```

I have 4 worker nodes and a jump server
Issue I am facing is that I am able to access the docker registry on ingress address from the jump host but from worker nodes it is failing with error , so when i create any pods with images from registry they also fail with below error

Worker and Jump host are in same subnet

```
request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

I have tried placing the service IP and the registry ingress host in /etc/hosts copying the certs to /etc/docker.certs.d/registryname .
Any hint would be great

Cluster information:
Kubernetes version: v1.19.8-eks-96780e
kubectl version o/p :
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20+", GitVersion:"v1.20.4-eks-6b7464", GitCommit:"6b746440c04cb81db4426842b4ae65c3f7035e53", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-03-19T19:35:50Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/arm64"}

Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19+", GitVersion:"v1.19.8-eks-96780e", GitCommit:"96780e1b30acbf0a52c38b6030d7853e575bcdf3", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-03-10T21:32:29Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Cloud being used: AWS

Installation method: EKS

EDIT 1

I checked on one worker node to find the CRI , kubelet process is as below , so I think CRI is docker

```
/usr/bin/kubelet --cloud-provider aws --config /etc/kubernetes/kubelet/kubelet-config.json --kubeconfig /var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig --container-runtime docker
```

but i did see both dockerd and containerd processes running on the worker node.

Also on checking the docker service logs I got same error.

```
Container Engine
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-06-14 08:31:57 UTC; 4 days ago
Docs: https://docs.docker.com
Process: 12574 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-setup-runtimes.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 12571 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /run/docker (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 12579 (dockerd)
Tasks: 23
Memory: 116.5M
CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
└─12579 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
Jun 19 02:23:45 ip-xxxxx dockerd[12579]: time=“2021-06-19T02:23:45.876987774Z” level=error msg=“Handler for POST /v1.40/images/create returned error: Get https://xxxx: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)”
```

Comment: Hello @user3129322. Could you please try to edit `/etc/hosts` and comment out the `::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback` line? So it would look like this: `#::1    localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback`.

Comment: these are loopback entries , can they be causing anything ?

Comment: Some people were experiencing the same issue and it was connected with IPv6 and the registry. It's worth checking before we dig deeper into this.

Comment: I tried the IPv6 part , also a case was raised with AWS they told to enable cross zone load balancing but that also didnt help , further update was that it is happening only on nodes which are on different AZ Than on which registry pod is running, I have run only on replica as don't have RWX type of storage.

Comment: So, was the difference between AZ and registry pod the cause of your issue? Have you managed to solve it?

Comment: not solved till now , waiting for further AWS update , ll keep it posted